# Code to IE first, then the "good" browsers? Or the other way...?

Tags: internet-explorer

What do you do first?

One of my mentors told me the best thing to do is code to a standards-compliant browser first, and then go back and fix IE.

I'm starting to think this is backwards, and that I should be thinking about IE from the very start.

Thoughts?

(PS, where can I learn "everything you need to know about dealing with IE"?)

Answer (score 1):

As far as my exp goes things that work properly for IE9 (also IE8) also works good for Firefox 4.0 and Chrome, but generally they break in IE7.
So it would be better to fix IE7 after you do away with other browsers.